# What does "españoles" legitimante mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I am researching family and this shows up in documents in early 19th century Mexico, in this case a birth registry.

I'd like to know what it means. I'm assuming it has something to do with being European only (in fact, the parties are Basque), but I am not sure.

Comment: Could you please show us some more context on the document? Copying the sentence in which this occurs would be very helpful

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't even understand the title. Are you asking for "españoles" or are you asking for "legitimante"? Why the quotes on "españoles"?  You can give more details or you an even share an image of those birth certificates so we could better help you.

Comment: What kind of document? Is it a legal document?

Answer (score 4):

**Legitimante** is the one that executes the action of the verb **legitimar**.

According to the D.R.A.E

[**legitimar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N53t0Dx)

> 1. tr. Convertir algo en legítimo.
> 2. tr. Probar o justificar la verdad de algo o la calidad de alguien o algo conforme a las leyes.
> 3. tr. Hacer legítimo al hijo que no lo era.

This verb translates to **legitimize** in English

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

**[legitimize](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/legitimize)**

> to make something legal or acceptable

But "españoles legitimante" makes no sense. Notice that the first word is in plural but the second isn't. If more than one Spanish people signed those documents to legitimize them, it should say "españoles legitimante**s**". Maybe it's a typo and it says **legítimamente**, the adverb that express that those persons had already legally proven to be from Spain and there was no futher need to proof it again.

If your document says "D.Pedro Pizarro y Dña.María Carmona, españoles legítimamente" or something like that, it means that according to the laws, D.Pedro and Dña.María, were considered Spanish. Notice that Mexico were part of the Spanish Empire until its independence in 1821, it doesn't have to mean that they were born in Europe. It depends on the age of the documents.

Comment: Your example is very similar to my document. I had thought that it might mean that the couple (my husband's like 4th or 5th great grandparents) were considered Spanish--meaning not mixed. Is this a correct understanding? I am, unfortunately attempting to read a document that is roughly 200 years old, so letters are faded. Looking at it a second time, it definitely says legitimante--no s--but it was handwritten. I think the reference is to the parents as they are named prior to the phrase as per your example. Thank you very much for your help. Cheryl Zapien

Comment: @CherylZapien You're welcome. If the word is "legitimante" it means that the parents legally recognize the newly born as their son [hijo legítimo]. If they were "legitimamente españoles", as I have stated it got nothing to do with the "purity" of their blood or the place where they were born. They could have been born in Manila (Philippine Islands), La Habana (Cuba) or Mérida (México) and they would have been legally Spanish citizens. If you scan the document and edit the question, we can improve the help. You know where to find us. Cheers